# Create a shortcut wilth izpack maven plugin

Tags: xml, maven-plugin, izpack

I created a project with the izpack maven plugin org.codehaus.izpack version 1.0-alpha-5.

The problem is I cannot create shortcuts for my application (windows), the shortcut panel is displayed empty... and there are no errors.

All the files exist and I tried to be based in a standard example from the web.. no sucesss..

The install.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <res id="shortcutSpec.xml" src="./shortcutSpec.xml" />
</resources>
<native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll"/> 
<variables>
    <variable name="DesktopShortcutCheckboxEnabled" value="true" />
</variables>
<panels>
    <panel classname="HelloPanel"/>
    <panel classname="InfoPanel"/>
    <panel classname="LicencePanel"/>
    <panel classname="TargetPanel"/>
    <panel classname="PacksPanel"/>
    <panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
    <panel classname="ShortcutPanel"/>
</panels>
```

in the shortcutSpec.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>

<shortcuts>
<!--skipIfNotSupported/-->
<programGroup defaultName="company\product" location="startMenu"/> 

<shortcut name="product" target="C:\Program Files\product\product.exe" description="Creating Gui Icon on the Desktop" 
workingDirectory="$INSTALL_PATH" iconFile="C:\Program Files\product\icon.ico" initialState="normal" programGroup="yes" desktop="yes" applications="yes" 
startMenu="yes" startup="no">

<createForPack name="product.exe"/>
</shortcut>

<shortcut
name="Documentation" target="C:\Program Files\product\doc\asdfsadfasf.docx" 
workingDirectory="$INSTALL_PATH" iconFile="C:\Program Files\product\icon.ico"
description="Launch documentation" initialState="normal" programGroup="yes" desktop="yes" 
applications="yes" startMenu="yes" startup="no">

<createForPack name="product.exe"/>
</shortcut>

</shortcuts>
```

Help me please.....

Comment: Please look at the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419830/izpack-create-shortcut-on-windows-7/35627201#35627201. It may help you find the possible causes for this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

The value for `createForPack` element of shortcut must be one of the pack name specified under packs. If this pack is not selected while installation, the respective shortcut is omitted automatically. For example, in the `install.xml` file:

```
...

<packs>
   <pack  name="Core" required="yes" preselected="yes">`
...
```

and in the `shortcutSpec.xml` file:

```
...

<shortcut programGroup="yes"
        desktop="yes"
        applications="no"
        startMenu="yes"
        startup="no"
        iconFile="$INSTALL_PATH\Icon.ico"
        iconIndex="0"`
        ...
        initialState="noShow">

    <createForPack name="Core"/>
</shortcut>
```

Here the name `Core` is the same in both files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on 64 bit Windows? If so, you'll need the 64 bit version of the dll:

```
<native type="izpack" name="ShellLink_x64.dll">
    <os family="windows" />
</native>
```

This is just a guess, but I know I ran into this myself developing for both 32 and 64 bit platforms.