# izpack: Create shortcut on windows 7

Tags: xml, windows, izpack

I use izpack to create an installer for my application. So far I was able to create the installer and on my linux machine everything is fine. 
The problem is that on the windows machines I tested it on (Win7 6bits) the installer did not show the shortcut panel. 
 
I did read the documentation troubleshooting section and took care that I have the natives in my installer.
 Same goes for the shortcut xml file, they are in the installer in the resources path. I also read that most likely it is a case sensitive typo or something similar simple but could not figure it out. Here is my shortcut xml:

```
<shortcuts>
<programGroup defaultName="SteamNet" location="applications"/>
<shortcut
    name = "One Click Wonder"
    target = "$INSTALL_PATH\oneclickwonder.bat"
    commandLine = ""
    workingDirectory= "$INSTALL_PATH"
    description="Minimal Desktop Timer"
    iconFile="$INSTALL_PATH\images\windows_icon.ico"
    iconIndex="0"
    initialState="noShow"
    programGroup="yes"
    desktop="yes"
    applications="yes"
    startMenu="yes"
    startup="yes"/>
</shortcuts>
```

And this is my install.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<installation version="1.0">
  <info>
    <appname>Test</appname>
    <appversion>1</appversion>
  </info>
  <guiprefs width="600" height="480" resizable="no">
  </guiprefs>
  <locale>
    <langpack iso3="eng"/>
  </locale>
  <panels>
    <panel classname="ShortcutPanel"/>
  </panels>
  <packs>
    <pack name="Test" required="yes">
      <description>Description</description>
    </pack>
  </packs>
  <resources>
    <res src="shortcutSpec.xml" id="shortcutSpec.xml"/>
  </resources>
  <natives>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink_x64.dll"/>
</natives>
</installation>
```

But i can't display the shortcut panel in my installer ... !

Comment: Please state if you are using IzPack 4.x or IzPack 5

Comment: I'm using IzPack 5 !

Comment: The same issue here. Both 32 and 64 DLLs are successfully packed into install.jar\com\izforge\izpack\bin\native\izpack , but no Shortcut panel step in wizard

Comment: @dkane: I resolved this problem, ensure that your shortcut xml file in written and all file that you refer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I compared this to a working installer file here which in contrast contains the following `<natives>` setting:

```
<natives>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll" />
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink_x64.dll" />
</natives>
```

When using a 32-Bit Java Runtime the 32-Bit ShellLink.dll will be used which is missing in your setup.

Comment: But i'm using Windows 64 bit and Jdk 64bit ! I don't need to include a 32bit dll

Comment: You should do this anyway as you cannot know what JDK the potential user will use. Did you also try with an additional InstallPanel in your install.xml?

Comment: I already add the 2 ddl but the same error ! What i try to add a PacksPanel ? Thanks

Comment: I already have an installPanel why i try to add an installPanel, please can you explain more ?

Comment: Your example above is only listing <panel classname="ShortcutPanel"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93812/discussion-between-marwen-bkh-and-torsten).

Comment: Ah yes . I already add the installPanel and i have the same issue !!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are a few known issues with `ShortcutPanel`. After extensive <del>trial-and-error</del> testing I have found that the following requirements have to be satisfied in order for it to display correctly:

- The `<lateShortcutInstall/>` tag in the shorctuts XML file **must only be present if you want to show** `ShortcutPanel` **before** `InstallPanel`. If your `ShortcutPanel` comes after the installation step, **your shurtcut panel will not be shown!**
- Your `<native>` tags must be enclosed within a `<natives>` tag,
- Add the `<skipIfNotSupported />` tag to the beginning of the `<shortcuts>` element,
- Double check your shortcuts XML file as it may have incorrect attribute names and/or missing quotes. Many users have reported such issues and it may be that there is an incorrect website that a lot of people copy-paste from. The specification for shortcut attributes can be found [here](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IZPACK/Shortcut+Specification).
- Check whether the native DLLs are packaged into the installer JAR. For the ShellLink DLLs unpack the JAR and look inside: `com/izforge/izpack/bin/native` (**and NOT** `com/izforge/izpack/bin/native/izpack/`)<sup>1</sup>,
- And finally, this is a bit trivial, but check whether your shortcuts XML file is where you think it is and that it has the correct name.

---

**Footnotes:**

1. I am using IzPack version **5.0.6**.